# вывод даты из Unix

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Есть сайт где администратор может менять часовой пояс, после того как администратор выбрал часовой пояс, все операции(оплата, регистрация и т.д.) фиксируются в бд(формат Unix, timestamp) уже в новом часовом поясе. Значение часового пояса загружается из базы и передается в функцию: `date_default_timezone_set($value);` Например: `Asia/Aden`.

Если пытаюсь вывести текущее время на сайте то все работает.
  После этого совершаю какую-либо операцию, чтобы время зафиксировалось в базе. 
Но когда вытаскиваю значение из бд получаю московское время, а не то что я выбрал.  Как это можно исправить?

Comment: timestamp не зависит от таймзоны, т.е значения всегда в GTM +0

Comment: @tcpack4, а можно как-то сделать чтобы оно текущее время записывало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем нашел как выйти из ситуации. Добавил `date_default_timezone_set('Значение_из_БД')` не только на сайте, где фиксируется время операции, но и на странице администратора, где все это отображается